# What is the single word for <1/3> (one-third)?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

The word "quarter" means <1/4> (one-forth).

Is there a single word that means <1/3> (one-third)?

Comment: What about the word "third" itself doesn't satisfy you? And "quarter" denotes one "fourth" only in the sense that "half" denotes one "second" -- it's not a helpful way to think of the concept of "quarter".

Comment: There is "tertiary" and "ternary", but they are used in completely different ways than "quarter". Stick with "third".

Comment: "One fourth" and "three fourths" are much more often used in US English than British.

Comment: 50%, one half, a half; **33.33%, one third, a third**; 25%, one quarter, a quarter; 10%, one tenth, a tenth etc.

Comment: @Rosie, <third> isn't just ambiguous but has a common meaning. "*I need it for a quarter year*" vs "*I need it for a third year*".

Comment: 'Riding' had a limited application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write one in three as the term means the same thing as one-third.
But there is no word for one-third similar to a quarter for one-fourth.

Comment: What's wrong with "a third"?

Comment: A third is also the right term of one-third.

Comment: `Tierce` was once used but is severely archaic.

Comment: @HotLicks, see the reply to the 1st comment under the q.